# Having difficulties using a darlington (BD681) to drive a 12V fan from an Arduino

Tags: arduino, transistors, darlington

I'm trying to power a 12v fan using a darlington so I can control the speed from an Arduino. When I wire up as below nothing happens, even though I'm sending a PWM signal:

[Circuit diagram http://img809.imageshack.us/img809/5261/wireissue.png](http://img809.imageshack.us/img809/5261/wireissue.png)

Have I wired up the transistor incorrectly?

Transistor: http://www.bitsbox.co.uk/data/transistor/BD681.pdf

Comment: Draw a circuit would you please

Comment: Are you providing power to the Arduino itself?

Comment: Please draw a proper circuit. Edit your question and hit Ctrl+M, the current image is unreadable. Check your breadboard, most rows along the side are have one or two interruptions half way (Arduino's GND connection). Possibly add a picture of your setup aswell.

Comment: You drew an PNP transistor and gave a datasheet for a NPN transisitor. Which one is it?

Comment: Are you sure about the diode polarity?

Answer (score 3):

The diode in your drawing is backwards.

As such, all the current is flowing through the diode, and you're not getting enough voltage to even turn the fan on.

[image]